# Qt program crashing without a message

Tags: c++, qt

I have the following piece of code;

```
void MainWindow::saveFile()
{
    Editor *editor = dynamic_cast<Editor*>(tabWindow->currentWidget());
    QFileInfo *fileInfo = editor->getFileInformation();
    QString fullFileName = fileInfo->absoluteFilePath();
    QFile file(fullFileName);
    file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
    QString text = editor->toPlainText();

    file.write(QByteArray::fromStdString(text.toStdString()));
    file.close();
}
```

When this is connected through the following piece;

```
connect(save, &QAction::triggered, this, &MainWindow::saveFile);
```

the program crashed when the event is invoked. If the connection is disabled the program works fine. I cannot tell what the problem is even after going through it several times. I tried it on Windows 10 and Ubuntu 15.10 and had exactly same problem. What am I doing wrong?

save is declared in header file as;

```
QAction *save = nullptr;
```

and then defined in same file as saveFile() function as;

```
save = new QAction(tr("Save"), this);
save->setShortcut(QKeySequence(tr("Ctrl+S")));
fileMenu->addAction(save);
connect(save, &QAction::triggered, this, &MainWindow::saveFile);
```

Comment: Are you sure `editor` is not null? I would always check the result of a dynamic_cast<>() or qobject_cast<>() before using the pointer.

Comment: @drescherjm: I've tried to check if editor is null but it seems execution is not even reaching the function body.

Comment: Is `save` dynamically allocated?

Comment: @drescherjm: yes, see the edit above.

Comment: Run it in a debugger and check where exactly it crashes. Regarding "and then defined in same file as saveFile() function as”: what does “in the same file” mean? Is the code executed before saveFile() is called?

Comment: Unrelated sidenote: There’s no point increating QFileInfo objects on the heap/passing them by pointer, just pass it by value/reference and avoid possible leaks.

Comment: @Frank Osterfeld; no, the last piece of code is defined in another function which is called during initialization of the program befall saveFile().

Comment: Use `qobject_cast()` instead of `dynamic_cast()`.